How can I call a self defined function on Emacs startup?
I'm very new to Emacs and i would like to know why the following doesn't work for me:
When I run Emacs, I would like to have my ~/ buffer displayed. I previously defined my own function to get back to the home directory by adding the following code to my init.el file:
(defun home ()
  "Open the home directory"
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/"))

This works well and I manage to get to the desired directory with M-x home. After that I wanted to make Emacs execute this code on startup in order to get directed to my home directory instantly. I did that by adding this code to my init.el file:
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'home)

However, this doesn't seem to work and I think it has something to do with the fact that I am trying to use a function that I defined myself. I suspect that because if I add
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'find-file "~/") 

instead of the previous code, it works.
My question is why doesn't it work when I use 'home and what can I change to make it work? And yes, the home function is defined before I try to call it with the hook.

It works for me.

Did you define the function before the add-hook call in your init.el?

Works for me too. @mmmmmm: it actually does not matter in this case. All that gets added to the hook with add-hook is the symbol, so as long as the function is defined before the hook is run, it will work. And since emacs-startup-hook runs after loading init files, as long as both the defun and the add-hook are in some init file, it should work. Try with emacs -Q -l /tmp/init.el with init.el  containing the defun and the add-hook in either order.

The problem is not that you define your own function and call it. The problem is that the splash screen is shown last and so the buffer that displays the home directory is hidden. Try:
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'home)
(defun home ()
   (find-file "~/"))

You don't need to make home an interactive function (aka command) unless you want to bind it to a key or want to call it with M-x home.
BTW, whatever you did to make you think that (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'find-file "~/") worked is wrong. Save your .emacs and replace it with this:
(setq debug-on-error t)

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'find-file "~/")

When you try to start emacs, you will get an error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments #<subr find-file> 0)
  find-file()
  run-hooks(after-init-hook delayed-warnings-hook)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()

You can only add functions that take no arguments to "normal" hooks like these (there are "abnormal" hooks but you don't need to worry about them for now). So the only way to do it is the way you tried to do it at first: define your own function that takes no arguments and add it to the hook.

You could also add an anonymous function (a so-called lambda function), but over time you will find that for several good reasons it's best to use a named function as @NickD recommends. Anyway, here's how you'd do it with an anonymous function: (add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (find-file "~/")))
